# How to get rid of extra json keys from MongoDB result

Tags: json, mongodb, restheart, cjson

I have just started using MongoDB and RESTHeart api server.

I wish to replace my existing DB with MongoDB and existing DB too receives a json from the rest api, I thought the change would be little. So, below is the issue:

When I query MongoDB, this is what I get

```
{
    "_collection-props-cached": false,
    "_embedded": {
        "rh:doc": [
            {
                "_etag": {
                    "$oid": "56ff559b7ea5c11edc8f93b7"
                },
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "56ff559b7ea5c11edc8f93b6"
                },
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "/presence/active_watchers/56ff559b7ea5c11edc8f93b6"
                    }
                },
                "callid": "1-12285@10.0.1.168",
                "contact": "sip:service@10.0.1.168:5060;transport=UDP",
                "event": "presence",
            },
            {
                "_etag": {
                    "$oid": "56ff55897ea5c11edc8f93b5"
                },
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "56ff55897ea5c11edc8f93b4"
                },
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "/presence/active_watchers/56ff55897ea5c11edc8f93b4"
                    }
                },
                "callid": "1-12285@10.0.1.168",
                "contact": "sip:service@10.0.1.168:5060;transport=UDP",
                "event": "presence",
                "event_id": "",
            }
        ]
    },
    "_etag": {
        "$oid": "56ff44807ea5c11edc8f93a6"
    },
    "_id": "active_watchers",
    "_links": {
        "curies": [],
        "self": {
            "href": "/presence/active_watchers"
        }
    },
    "_returned": 2,
    "descr": "subscriptions collection"
}
```

I am only interested in **rh_doc** array. My question is, is there a way I can just receive just the documents from the Monogo without the extra information.

The problem is, existing code expects just the array of values like `[{callid:"123",...},{callid:"234",...}]`and it has been coded that way in C using cJSON. It feels scary to touch the C code!!

Or may be if CJSON can delete the keys: **_etag, _id** etc.

**Edit**
This is how I query:

```
http  GET "http://localhost:8080/presence/active_watchers?filter={'presentity_uri':'sip:service-1@opensipstest.org'}&filter={'event':'presence'}"
```

Thanks

Comment: If I get you right, you might want to use [projection](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-projection)

Comment: How are you querying the collection to get the current result?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Thanks. I think that's what is required, I am looking into it now.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I have edited the post with the URI I am trying for the query.

Answer (score 0):

In the second argument of your find statement you can specify which fields to include.

E.g.

```
db.someCollection.find({}, {_embedded: 1})
```

Or if you only want the nested rh:docs field:

```
db.someCollection.find({}, {"_embedded.rh:doc": 1})
```

Comment: Thanks John. `{_embedded: 1}` gives 0 results so I tried `{_embedded: 0}`, this gives the output but when I try same using restheart I get 0 documents in both case.
`{
    "_collection-props-cached": false,
    "_etag": {
        "$oid": "56ff44807ea5c11edc8f93a6"
    },
    "_id": "active_watchers",
    "_links": {
        "curies": [],
        "self": {
            "href": "/presence/active_watchers?filter={'_embedded.rh:doc':'1'}"
        }
    },
    "_returned": 0,
    "descr": "subscriptions collection"
}
`

Comment: Add keys={'_embedded':1} as a get parameter to your request to restheart.

Comment: I tried `keys={'_embedded':1}`and `keys={'rh:doc':1}"` and `keys={'_embedded.rh:doc':1}"` and with `&np` what I get is either the full document as in the question or I get just the properties keys and not the actual keys. Don't know what wrong I am doing.

Comment: Using `http://localhost:8080/presence/active_watchers?filter={'presentity_uri':'sip:service-1@opensipstest.org'}&filter={'event':'presence'}&np&keys={'_id':0}&keys={'_etag':0}` I am able to remove the unwanted properties. And yes earlier I was working on version **1.1.7** now I changed it to **2.0.0 beta**